# IFERROR() doesn't work and still return !REF#

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula to import JSON into Google Sheets but in some scenarios, the requested fields do not exist and in such case I'd like the formula to return nothing instead of `!REF#`. In addition, I configured that if another specific cell in the same row is empty, the formula output will be blank either. I tried using `=IFERROR((IF(ISBLANK(C5),"",ImportJSON("https://maps.googleapis.////com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="&C5&"&fields=opening_hours&language=iw&key=AI**********","/result/opening_hours/weekday_text", "noHeaders"))),"")` but `!REF#` is returned anyway. What did I do wrong?

Comment: May be the formula has not enough place, try to erase the entire column below (and may be also the entire row on the right and side) !

Comment: What is the text when you hover over the ref error?

Comment: I have never seen ImportJSON() as a function in google sheets.  Did you create a custom function?  Can you provide a link to a sheet the demonstrates this?